# Javascript - Preenchendo Textbox com números, strings e datas num boleto

Tags: javascript, string, data, textbox, number-format

Estou tentando fazer com que um boleto seja preenchido automaticamente ao  selecionar uma linha de uma tabela. No caso, existem textbox (ou inputs do tipo text) que devem ser preenchidas com alguns valores. Minha função é

```
function verBoleto(nossonumero,valor,dataemissao,datavencimento,razaosocial){
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate());
    $('#dataProc1').datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    });
    // Data de processamento é a data atual.
    $("#dataProc1").datepicker('setDate',d);
    $("#dataProc2").val($("#dataProc1").val());

    $('#nossoNum1').val(nossonumero);
    $('#valDoc1').val(valor).replace('.',',');
    $('#dataDoc1').val(dataemissao);
    $('#vencDoc1').val(datavencimento);
    $('#sacado1').val(razaosocial);
}
```

Mas por enquanto sem muito resultado. O campo nossonumero é preenchido sem problemas. O campo de valor está mostrando número com ponto antes das casas decimais ou invés de vírgula. As datas de emissão e vencimento estão vindo com número com vírgula (01/06/2015 vem 0.00008271298593879239, por exemplo). E a razão social nem aparece preenchida no Textbox.

O que dá pra fazer nesse caso?

Comment: O que dá `console.log(nossonumero,valor,dataemissao,datavencimento,razaosocial);` na primeira linha dessa função?

Comment: De onde vêm os valores dos parâmetros do JS?

Comment: Sergio, como eu faço esse console.log?Paulo, Os valores dos parâmetros vem de uma consulta SQL e ficam exibidos em uma tabela.

Comment: @GustavoHoppeLevin abre a consola premindo F12 ou com o botão direito na página selecionando "inpecionar"

Comment: Pelo debbuger, a função do onclick fica, por exemplo: onclick="verBoleto(63271038641,687.75,30/05/2015,18/06/2015,NOME DE TESTE)". Já consegui o esquema do valor de converter o ponto pra vírgula, então faltam só as datas e o nome de razão social (ele acusa estar faltando um ')' devido a razão social ser um nome completo com espaços em branco no meio).